# Installing OpenStack With Puppet

Tags: puppet, middleware, openstack

Trying to install openstack with puppet 3.2 over CentOS 6.4.
when doing puppet agent --test
i get:

`Error: cloud not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declartion: Database_user[@localhost] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/modules/mysql/manifests/server/account/security.pp at line 13; cannot redeclare on node localhost.localdomain`

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly as the error says - you have the `@localhost` `database_user` declared twice. The error message clearly points to line 13 of security.pp. Start there.